# how to address object dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a need to build some search criteria using the inputs user entered.

```
string searchText1 = "";
string searchText2 = "";
string searchText3 = "";

searchText1 = scCB1.Text + op1.Text + cr1.Text;
searchText2 = scCB2.Text + op2.Text + cr2.Text;
searchText3 = scCB3.Text + op3.Text + cr3.Text;
```

where scCB1, op1, cr1, ... are the combobox and text fields on GUI.

Is there a way I could use a loop to replace the hard coded statements (they look awkward)?

```
For (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{  
   //    searchText(i) = scCB(i).Text + op(i).Text +cr(i).Text)
}
```

As a rookie in programming, I understand if I display and build only one set of fields on GUI, then I'll be able to loop in the code.  But I am curious how i could address the name of the objects dynamically. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: `scCB(i)` have you considered using arrays? The syntax is essentially what you want: `scCBArray[i]`

Comment: You´re on the right track already, just use an array or a list instead of three different variables.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is being downvoted. The question is clear, well-formed and shows a reasonable usage and expectation. While the solution is fairly simple, this is a question that most developers will have asked themselves at some point and thus is a relevant question for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the controls are on a `GroubBox` named **options**:

```
string[] searchText = new string[3];
for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
   {
        searchText[i - 1] = options.Control["scCB" + i.Tostring()] +
                        options.Control["ops" + i.Tostring()] +
                        options.Control["cr" + i.Tostring()];
   }
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere I edited my answer

Comment: Far easier would be to simply loop from zero to 2.

Comment: @HimBromBeere in here `options.Control["scCB" + i.Tostring()]` control names start from 1. so we should have `i-1` where I did, or `i+1` when getting controls by name `options.Control["scCB" + (i + 1).Tostring()]`;

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make an array containing your text boxes and other elements, this way your can easily reference them inside a loop:

```
TextBox[] boxes = {scCB1, scCB2, scCB3}; // do same for op1..3 and cr1..3
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{     
  string searchText = boxes[i].Text + ops[i].Text + cr[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: `searchText`s will have to be in a collection as well. And please explain why to use array and not `List`?

Comment: @Guy, I am suggesting to use an array instead of a list as I assume the count of textboxes to be determined and not to be changed on runtime. If you would add textboxes somewhere in the process then sure, use list or arrayList.

Comment: @Guy: Most of the argument between array/list has evaporated since they share most of their features by both of them implementing `IEnumerable<T>`. It's easy to jump from one to the other, neither option locks you in. However, as OP wants an indexed approach, arrays are the go-to solution. Note that you can index a list (`myList[i]`), but it's more idiomatic to refer to an array when focusing on indexed element retrieval.

Comment: To the guy downvoting my answer: please explain the reason.

Comment: Nobody down-votes your answer.